# Creating and mounting a second ZFS drive in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive, zfs

I have two discs: a SSD and a regular hard drive in my laptop. Ubuntu installed on the SSD drive which is 128GB. The second hard drive is 1TB. I installed Ubuntu using ZFS and I would like the second hard drive to have the same filesystem. I need a clear step by step answer on how to include the 1TB drive as a ZFS disc so that it is automatically mounted when i boot the laptop. This is my current setup:

```
sudo lsblk
 
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0              7:0    0  61.9M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1405
loop1              7:1    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
loop2              7:2    0 248.8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop3              7:3    0 155.6M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/1232
loop4              7:4    0  61.9M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1494
loop5              7:5    0 162.2M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/1406
loop6              7:6    0  45.9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/575
loop7              7:7    0  43.6M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/15177
loop8              7:8    0  45.9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/582
loop9              7:9    0  81.3M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop10             7:10   0  44.7M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/15904
loop11             7:11   0   284K  1 loop  /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/10
loop12             7:12   0   284K  1 loop  /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14
sda                8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
zd0              230:0    0   500M  0 disk  
└─keystore-rpool 253:0    0   484M  0 crypt /run/keystore/rpool
nvme0n1          259:0    0 119.2G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1      259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/grub
│                                           /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2      259:2    0     2G  0 part  
│ └─cryptoswap   253:1    0     2G  0 crypt [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p3      259:3    0     2G  0 part  
└─nvme0n1p4      259:4    0 114.7G  0 part
```

As you can see, the second hard disk appears as sda - 931.5G. It is not formatted as ZFS and it is currently invisible once the system boots. I am new to this and do not understand it.Please can someone help me with the following:

1. Exactly **how** do i format sda so that it has ZFS on it?
2. What is the 'mountpoint' for sda? I simply want additional storage space so can i mount it as /home when i already have a /home partition?

Comment: How is your ZFS configuration ? How do you use the new disk ? ZFS is not a simple filesystem, but an andvnced tool for disk-management, volume.management with colnes, snapshots, and lots oft other advanced power-tools for systems with many large disks - and not really for a desktop machine or home-server.